# Remove multiple spaces and new lines inside of String

Tags: ruby, string

Suppose we have string like this:

```
Hello, my\n       name is Michael.
```

How can I remove that new line and strip those spaces after that into one inside of string to get this?

```
Hello, my name is Michael.
```

Answer (score 212, accepted):

check out Rails `squish` method:

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-squish

Comment: The simplest and the most elegant solution. Thanks. But there's one thing, this method is defined in Rails, so it'll work only in Rails applications, luckily that's my case.

Comment: As Kreeki said a tad unclearly, this is a Rails method, not a Ruby method.

Comment: For a non-Rails context, use `some_string.strip.gsub(/\s+/, " ")` which is exactly what squish does.

Answer (score 42):

To illustrate Rubys built in **squeeze**:

```
string.gsub("\n", ' ').squeeze(' ')
```

Comment: Just be aware: squeeze will compress ALL strings that come in runs of multiple characters. So 
    "Squeeze     my   application's   copy".squeeze => "Squeze my aplication's copy"

Comment: But `squeeze(' ')` just squeezes spaces. `"Squeeze my application's copy".squeeze(' ') => "Squeeze my application's copy"`.

Answer (score 22):

The simplest way would probably be

```
s = "Hello, my\n       name is Michael."
s.split.join(' ') #=> "Hello, my name is Michael."
```

Answer (score 15):

Try This:

```
s = "Hello, my\n       name is Michael."
s.gsub(/\n\s+/, " ")
```

Comment: This is actually the best "plain ruby" answer, and works properly for stripping leading spaces from a multiline string.

Answer (score 7):

```
my_string = "Hello, my\n       name is Michael."
my_string = my_string.gsub( /\s+/, " " )
```

Comment: he would also like to remove the `\n` ideally (I feel) it should be replace with a space in case of something like `"Hello,\nMy name is Michael"`

Answer (score 5):

this regex will replace instance of 1 or more white spaces with 1 white space, p.s `\s` will replace all white space characters which includes `\s\t\r\n\f`:

```
a_string.gsub!(/\s+/, ' ')
```

Similarly for only carriage return

```
str.gsub!(/\n/, " ")
```

First replace all `\n` with white space, then use the remove multiple white space regex.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for my purposes to remove multiples spaces but maintain single space between words.

Answer (score 4):

Use [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001186):

```
s = "Hello, my\n       name is Michael."
s.gsub(/\s+/, " ")
```

Comment: output would not be correct in the case of `"Hello,\nMy name is Michael"`. Ideally you would want a space where there is a `\n`

Answer (score 3):

```
Use squish
currency = " XCD"
str = currency.squish
 str = "XCD" #=> "XCD"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add just the `squish` method (and nothing else) to Ruby by including just this Ruby Facet:

https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/blob/master/lib/core/facets/string/squish.rb

```
require 'facets/string/squish'
```

Then use

```
"my    \n   string".squish #=> "my string"
```

Doesn't require Rails.